# How to insert a function in where clause on Qlik Sense?

Tags: qliksense

I am trying to use a `MAX` function inside `WHERE` clause on `Qlik Sense`.

I have charged a calendar and I have to make the sum of a specific value filtering it by max month of the max year specified. If I do the following statement separately:

```
Max({<Year={"$(=max(Year))"}>}Month)
```

it shows me correctly the max month of each row.

Instead of this, if I try to use this filter to filter my value it shows me only null values. This is the expression that I am using by the moment:

```
Sum({<Month=Max({<Year={"$(=max(Year))"}>}Month)>}Import)
```

How can I filter by month of the last year specified?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There's two thing that needs to be added for your expression to work: The dollar expansion for the whole max expression and an outer expression for the year (unless you want to sum for all months x for all years, where x is the largest month of the latest year)

```
sum({< Month = {"$(=max({<Year = {"$(=max(Year))"}>} Month}"}, 
     Year = {"$(=max(Year))"} >} Import }
```